# Change form style after hovering over h1 with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change form style on hovering over h1 with only css3?

The code goes something like this:

```
<div id="fast">
  <h1>headline</h1>
  <br>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" nam="fast_s" value="true">
    <div>
      <h2>change this</h2>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The css file:

```
#fast form {
  color: gray;
}
#fast h1:hover ~ #fast form {
  color: red;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEogpB

Comment: Should this only change the style *while* the `<h1>` is hovered, or do you want/need the style to persist after the `<h1>` hover ends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#fast h1:hover ~ form {
  color: red;
}
```

remove the second occurence of `#fast` since `~` is the general sibling selector: `a ~ b` matches `b` when it is a (subsequent) sibling of `a` but `#fast` is not a sibling of `h1`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azYXQo

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just replace `~ #fast form` with `+ form`

```
#fast form {
  color: gray;
}

#fast h1:hover + form {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: No, the adjacent sibling selector `+` won't work since between `h1` and `form` there's a `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

You target the siblings form next to h1 so you dont need to precise the parent #fast anymore :

```
#fast h1:hover ~ form {
  color: red;
}
```